# Gecko forms to powerBI in real time

Tags: powerbi, real-time, real-time-data

I need to get data entered into a gecko form into a PowerBI report in real time.

I have found a solution:
Gecko -> Web hook -> Pipedream -> Google Sheets -> PowerBI

But this is limited to a refresh every 30 minutes in power BI.
And we would prefer not to use 3rd party tools but to get the data direct from gecko to PowerBI or fabric.

I have also tried to create a streaming dataset in PowerBI. And using a
workflow in gecko to send to data to the datasets url.

[powerBI streaming dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp45y.png)

[gecko workflow sending webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or0am.png)